# MullionType errors in Revit API/Dynamo script

Tags: revit-api

I’m working on a Python script that takes a set of input lines and assigns a mullion to the corresponding gridline that they intersect. However, I’m getting a strange error:

[image: *Expected Mullion Type, Got Family Type*]

that I don’t know how to correct towards the end of the script. Python is telling me that it expected a MullionType and got a Family Type (see image). I’m using a modified version of Spring Nodes’ Collector.WallTypes that collects Mullion Types instead but the output of the node is a Family Type, which the script won’t accept. Any idea how to get the Mullion Type to feed into the final Python node?

SpringNodes script:

```
#Copyright(c) 2016, Dimitar Venkov
# @5devene, dimitar.ven@gmail.com

import clr

clr.AddReference("RevitServices")
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference("RevitNodes")
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)

def tolist(obj1):
    if hasattr(obj1,"__iter__"): return obj1
    else: return [obj1]

fn = tolist(IN[0])
fn = [str(n) for n in fn]
result, similar, names = [], [], []

fec = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(MullionType)
for i in fec:
    n1 = Element.Name.__get__(i)
    names.append(n1)
    if any(fn1 == n1 for fn1 in fn):
        result.append(i.ToDSType(True))
    elif any(fn1.lower() in n1.lower() for fn1 in fn):
        similar.append(i.ToDSType(True))

if len(result) > 0:
    OUT = result,similar
if len(result) == 0 and len(similar) > 0:
    OUT = "No exact match found. Check partial below:",similar
if len(result) == 0 and len(similar) == 0:
    OUT = "No match found! Check names below:", names
```

The SpringNodes script outputs a Family Type, even though the collector is for Mullion Types (see above image)

Here's my script:

```
import clr

# Import RevitAPI
clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

# Import DocumentManager and TransactionManager
clr.AddReference("RevitServices")
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager

# Import ToDSType(bool) extension method

clr.AddReference("RevitNodes")
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion)

from System import Array
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

import math 

doc =  DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument
app =  DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentUIApplication.Application


walls = UnwrapElement(IN[0])
toggle = IN[1]
inputLine = IN[2]
mullionType = IN[3]

wallSrf = []
heights = []
finalPoints = []
directions = []
isPrimary = []
projectedCrvs = []
keySegments = []
keySegmentsGeom = []
gridSegments = []
gridSegmentsGeom = []
gridLines = []
gridLinesGeom = []
keyGridLines = []
keyGridLinesGeom = []
projectedGridlines = []
lineDirections = []
gridLineDirection = []
allTrueFalse = []


if toggle == True:

    TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)

    for w, g in zip(walls,inputLine):
        pointCoords = []
        primary = []

        ## Get curtain wall element sketch line

        originLine = Revit.GeometryConversion.RevitToProtoCurve.ToProtoType( w.Location.Curve, True )
        originLineLength = w.Location.Curve.ApproximateLength

        ## Get curtain wall element height, loft to create surface

        for p in w.Parameters:
            if p.Definition.Name == 'Unconnected Height':       
                height = p.AsDouble()   
        topLine = originLine.Translate(0,0,height)
        srfCurves = [originLine,topLine]
        wallSrf = NurbsSurface.ByLoft(srfCurves)

        ## Get centerpoint of curve, determine whether it extends across entire gridline

        projectedCrvCenterpoint = []

        for d in g:

            lineDirection = d.Direction.Normalized()
            lineDirections.append(lineDirection)
            curveProject= d.PullOntoSurface(wallSrf)
            if abs(lineDirection.Z) == 1:
                if curveProject.Length >= height-.5:
                    primary.append(False)
                else:
                    primary.append(True)
            else:
                if curveProject.Length >= originLineLength-.5:
                    primary.append(False)
                else:
                    primary.append(True)
            centerPoint = curveProject.PointAtParameter(0.5)
            pointList = []
            projectedCrvCenterpoint.append(centerPoint)

            ## Project centerpoint of curve onto wall surface

            for h in [centerPoint]:
                pointUnwrap = UnwrapElement(centerPoint)
                pointList.append(pointUnwrap.X)
                pointList.append(pointUnwrap.Y)
                pointList.append(pointUnwrap.Z)
            pointCoords.append(pointList)
        finalPoints.append(pointCoords)
        isPrimary.append(primary)
        projectedCrvs.append(projectedCrvCenterpoint)


    TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()       
    TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)

    ##Gather all segments of gridline geometry

    for wall in UnwrapElement(walls):   
        gridSegments2 = []
        gridSegmentsGeom2 = []
        gridLines1 = []
        gridLinesGeom1 = []
        for id1 in wall.CurtainGrid.GetVGridLineIds():
            gridLinesGeom1.append(Revit.GeometryConversion.RevitToProtoCurve.ToProtoType(doc.GetElement(id1).FullCurve))
            gridLines1.append(doc.GetElement(id1))
            VgridSegments1 = []
            VgridSegmentsGeom1 = []
            for i in doc.GetElement(id1).AllSegmentCurves:
                VgridSegments1.append(i)
                VgridSegmentsGeom1.append(Revit.GeometryConversion.RevitToProtoCurve.ToProtoType(i,True))
            gridSegments2.append(VgridSegments1)
            gridSegmentsGeom2.append(VgridSegmentsGeom1)
        for id2 in wall.CurtainGrid.GetUGridLineIds():
            gridLinesGeom1.append(Revit.GeometryConversion.RevitToProtoCurve.ToProtoType(doc.GetElement(id2).FullCurve))
            gridLines1.append(doc.GetElement(id2))
            UgridSegments1 = []
            UgridSegmentsGeom1 = []
            for i in doc.GetElement(id2).AllSegmentCurves:
                UgridSegments1.append(i)
                UgridSegmentsGeom1.append(Revit.GeometryConversion.RevitToProtoCurve.ToProtoType(i,True))
            gridSegments2.append(UgridSegments1)
            gridSegmentsGeom2.append(UgridSegmentsGeom1)    
        gridSegments.append(gridSegments2)
        gridSegmentsGeom.append(gridSegmentsGeom2)
        gridLines.append(gridLines1)
        gridLinesGeom.append(gridLinesGeom1)

    boolFilter = [[[[b.DoesIntersect(x) for x in d] for d in z] for b in a] for a,z in zip(projectedCrvs, gridSegmentsGeom)]

    boolFilter2 = [[[b.DoesIntersect(x) for x in z] for b in a] for a,z in zip(projectedCrvs, gridLinesGeom)]

    ##Select gridline segments that intersect with centerpoint of projected lines

    for x,y in zip(boolFilter,gridSegments):
        keySegments2 = []
        keySegmentsGeom2 = []
        for z in x:
            keySegments1 = []
            keySegmentsGeom1 = []
            for g,l in zip(z,y):
                for d,m in zip(g,l):
                    if d == True:
                        keySegments1.append(m)
                        keySegmentsGeom1.append(Revit.GeometryConversion.RevitToProtoCurve.ToProtoType(m,True))
            keySegments2.append(keySegments1)
            keySegmentsGeom2.append(keySegmentsGeom1)
        keySegments.append(keySegments2)
        keySegmentsGeom.append(keySegmentsGeom2)

    ##Order gridlines according to intersection with projected points

    for x,y in zip(boolFilter2, gridLines):
        keyGridLines1 = []
        keyGridLinesGeom1 = []
        for z in x:

            for g,l in zip(z,y):
                if g == True:
                    keyGridLines1.append(l)
                    keyGridLinesGeom1.append(Revit.GeometryConversion.RevitToProtoCurve.ToProtoType(l.FullCurve,True))
        keyGridLines.append(keyGridLines1)
        keyGridLinesGeom.append(keyGridLinesGeom1)

    ##Add mullions at intersected gridline segments

    TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()
    TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)


    for x,y,z in zip(keyGridLines,keySegments,isPrimary):
        projectedGridlines1 = []
        for h,j,k in zip(x,y,z):
            for i in j:
                if i != None:
                    h.AddMullions(i,mullionType,k)
                    projectedGridlines1.append(h)
        projectedGridlines.append(projectedGridlines1)

else:
    None

if toggle == True:
    OUT = projectedGridlines

else:
    None

TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()
```

Apologies for the messiness of the code, it's a modification of another node that I've been working on. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bo,

Your problem is rooted in how Dynamo is wrapping elements to use with its own model. That last call `.ToDSType(True)` is the gist of the issue. MullionType class is a subclass (it inherits properties) from a ElementType class in Revit. When Dynamo team wraps that object into a custom wrapper they only wrote a top level wrapper that treats all ElementTypes the same, hence this outputs an ElementType/FamilyType rather than a specific MullionType.

First I would suggest that you replace the line of code in your code:

```
mullionType = IN[3]
```

with:

```
mullionType = UnwrapElement(IN[3])
```

This is their built in method for unwrapping elements to be used with calls to Revit API.

If that still somehow remains an issue, you could try and retrieve the MullionType object again, this time directly in your script, before you use it. You can do so like this:

```
for x,y,z in zip(keyGridLines,keySegments,isPrimary):
    projectedGridlines1 = []
    for h,j,k in zip(x,y,z):
        for i in j:
            if i != None:
                h.AddMullions(i,doc.GetElement(mullionType.Id),k)
                projectedGridlines1.append(h)
    projectedGridlines.append(projectedGridlines1)
```

This should make sure that you get the MullionType element before it was wrapped.

Again, try unwrapping it first, then GetElement() call if first doesn't work.

Comment: Unwrapping the input worked! The Unwrapping/ToDSType issues have been a difficult one to get my head around. I've noticed that when calling methods from the API, some methods require me to create a DSType element, others don't. It's all very confusing. Thanks for your help!